# Is there a way to change the root URL in python's Tornado web framework?

Tags: python, tornado

I have a Tornado web server with an application running on it such that when I go to:

*localhost:8888/*

I see my application's homepage. When I go to, for example,

- localhost:8888/static/image/logo.png
- localhost:8888/about
- localhost:8888/contact
- etc..

I get those relavant items as well.

My question is, is there a way to change the root location such that all of those URL's would replace the first part of the URL with:

- localhost:8888/myApplication/
- localhost:8888/myApplication/static/image/logo.png
- etc...

Sorry if this is a simple question! Can't seem to find the answer.

Note that I would like a solution other than to manually change all the page routing regex's to include that prefix.

Comment: Can you provide some code, how you define routes/handlers? Are you using Tornado's templates, do you use `static_url`, `reverse_url`?

Comment: You can read the  [tornado.web document](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application) send a `static_url_prefix` for server static files.

Comment: Tornado doesn't provide any way to do that. But, might I ask, what is the problem in manually changing the urls? All you have to do is use find/replace feature of your text editor.

Comment: I was hoping Tornado would provide a way. The issue is I'm proxying the web application on another server with an address like:

http://proxy-server/MyApplication

But Tornado gets confused with the static URLs thinking they should be at proxy-server/static/etc.. instead of proxy-server/MyApplication/static/etc... So I ended up hacking the static url function in tornado to prefix my application string. Not the best solution, but...

Comment: I believe we're looking for the Tornado equivalent to Django `SUB_SITE`. This is because if we are hosting multiple `tornado.web.Application`s on same host in either proxy or wsgiadapter mode attached to different mountpoints, we want apps to be configurable on any mountpoint without having to change all routes. (incidentally, Flask/Werkzeug route decorators don't seem to suffer this problem, but perhaps they are using `re.search` instead of `re.match` when route matching...).

Comment: Got exactly the same issue :( Trying to render the jupyter notebook in a proxy server, have to monkey patch everything. 
@cowbert  if you have any way now.

Comment: @OliverHu I used Pawan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35782558/2718295) see my [demo here](https://gist.github.com/cowbert/e5cf9fef52e24d2b2e330112deba6ed1)

Comment: @cowbert thanks.. I ended creating a reverse proxy server on top of Tornado to add the missing path back :( However, I still couldn't make it work end-to-end. Because the web proxy server Hadoop uses was built with Jetty 6.x which doesn't support WebSocket proxy :(

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `tornado.web` web framework, those root URLs are stored as regex within the web application object. So, one 'hacky' way to make this work is to change the regex.

Say your web application is setup as

```
my_application = tornado.web.Application([(r"/", my_handler), (r"/about", about_handler),])
```

you could iterate over the handlers and modify the regex for each of them, before you start the event loop, like so:

```
for handler in my_application.handlers[0][1]:
    handler.regex = re.compile(handler.regex.pattern.replace('/', '/myApplication/', 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Tornado 4.5+, I think you also have two options in monkeypatching [tornado.routing.PathMatches](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/routing.html#PathMatches).

1. `tornado.routing.PathMatches.__init__()`:

   Here you can prepend the original pattern with something like `r/\w*`. This may additionally beneficial if you also want to modify the original regex pattern to be open-ended on the right hand side (since the [original version](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/routing.html#PathMatches) always ensures `$` is at end of the regex pattern). This will ensure routing by path matching will follow Apache `RewriteRule` or Django router-style semantics (where you'll need to explicitly match on `^` and `$` if you need more specific path matching control)

   ```
   import re
   import tornado.routing
   from tornado.util import basestring_type

   def pathmatches_init(self, path_pattern):

       if isinstance(path_pattern, basestring_type):

           # restore path regex behavior to RewriteRule semantics

           # if not path_pattern.endswith('$'):
           #    path_pattern += '$'
           # self.regex = re.compile(path_pattern)

           if not path_pattern.startswith('^'):
               path_pattern = r'/\w*' + path_pattern

           self.regex = re.compile(path_pattern)
       else:
           self.regex = path_pattern

       assert len(self.regex.groupindex) in (0, self.regex.groups), \
           ("groups in url regexes must either be all named or all "
            "positional: %r" % self.regex.pattern)

       self._path, self._group_count = self._find_groups()

   tornado.routing.PathMatches.__init__ = pathmatches_init
   ```
2. `tornado.routing.PathMatches.match()`

   Instead of calling `re.match()` which only matches at beginning of the path, `re.search()` is called instead, since it will search the entire `request.path` for a match, and therefore match any URI prefix:

   ```
   import tornado.routing

   def pathmatches_match(self, request):
       # change match to search
       match = self.regex.search(request.path)
       if match is None:
           return None
       if not self.regex.groups:
           return {}

       path_args, path_kwargs = [], {}

       # Pass matched groups to the handler.  Since
       # match.groups() includes both named and
       # unnamed groups, we want to use either groups
       # or groupdict but not both.
       if self.regex.groupindex:
           path_kwargs = dict(
               (str(k), _unquote_or_none(v))
               for (k, v) in match.groupdict().items())
       else:
           path_args = [_unquote_or_none(s) for s in match.groups()]

       return dict(path_args=path_args, path_kwargs=path_kwargs)

   tornado.routing.PathMatches.match = pathmatches_match
   ```